# Javascript/GAS- Googlesheet to HTML table- Taking only first column

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that reads a google sheet and supposed to take data to HTML table.

```
function Getdata(){

const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws= ss.getSheetByName("Projects");
const headers= ws.getRange("A1:F").getValues();
const Project_State = headers[0][0];
const Start_Date = headers[0][1];
const End_Date = headers[0][2];
const Project_ID = headers[0][3];
const Project_Name = headers[0][4];
const Project_Code = headers[0][5];
const First_Name = headers[0][8];

const lr = ws.getLastRow();
const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-2).getDisplayValues();

const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Notify") 
htmlTemplate.Project_State= Project_State;
htmlTemplate.Start_Date= Start_Date;
htmlTemplate.End_Date= End_Date;
htmlTemplate.Project_ID= Project_ID ;
htmlTemplate.Project_Name=Project_Name;
htmlTemplate.Project_Code=Project_Code;
htmlTemplate.First_Name=First_Name;
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues=tableRangeValues;

const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
subject: 'Project End - Action Required',
htmlBody: htmlForEmail,
  });
}
```

From the research I have done, I have been able to show the headers of the sheet in the HTML table sent via email, I am however having a challenge in capturing row data from the sheet to HTM table. I am not sure if my range is off, or I am missing something. The thing is, I am only able to get the first column of data to my HTML table.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
        
    <title>Weekly Report</title>
    
  </head>
  <body style="padding:3em;">

<p>Hi Project Leader,</p>
<p>please see below for the latest updates on the projcets you manage.<br>
<br /> Team</p>
<div style=""background-color:blue; height:4px;></div>
<h3> Project Details </h3>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><?= Project_State ?></th>
<th><?= Start_Date ?></th>
<th><?= End_Date ?></th>
<th><?= Project_ID ?></th>
<th><?= Project_Name?></th>
<th><?= Project_Code ?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?tableRangeValues.forEach(r=>{?>
<tr>
<td><?=r[0]?></td>
<td><?=r[1]?></td>
<td><?=r[2]?></td>
<td><?=r[3]?></td>
<td><?=r[4]?></td>
<td><?=r[5]?></td>
</tr>
<?})?>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the structure of the google sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the row including the columns "A" to "F", I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-2).getDisplayValues();
```

#### To:

```
const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-2, 6).getDisplayValues();
```

- In your script, `getRange(2,1, lr-2)` is the cells of "A2:A" except for the bottom row. In order to retrieve the columns "A" to "F", I modified it to `getRange(2,1, lr-2, 6)`. In this case, the range is the cells of "A2:F" except for the bottom row.
- If you want to retrieve the rows from 2nd row to the last row, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-2).getDisplayValues();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-1, 6).getDisplayValues();
    ```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: thanks this worked fine for me. Last question am trying to put condition on the html part such that if the end date is less than current date, the row should be colored red on the HTML table `<th><?= End_Date ?></th>` which is `<td><?=r[2]?></td>` on the table values. How do I go about it?

Comment: @willy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do from your replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. And also, your new question is different from your this question. So in order to correctly understand about your new question, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks for your response. I have posted  the question in here  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866209/how-do-i-pass-unique-values-in-google-sheet-to-html-email-tempalet-in-gas-javasc)   Please help me if you can. Thanks

Comment: @willy Thank you for your response. I will check it. And when I could understand about your new question, I would like to think of the solution.