# How do I pass unique values in Google Sheet to HTML Email template

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping

I have a google sheet that has project data(project code, name, dates project leaders et.c) and I am trying to get row data for unique values in this case emails. If for example email **johndoe@testmail.com** appear x number of times, the row data should be captured and passed to html file then emailed to **johndoe@testmail.com** same case to other emails. So specific project leaders should receive emails on only the projects they lead. I have am newbie in JavaScript/GAs, and have done tonnes of research but could not get it to work. I will appreciate help with this.

Email script that reads the sheet

```
function Getdata(){

const ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws= ss.getSheetByName("Projects");
const headers= ws.getRange("A1:J").getValues();
const Project_Code = headers[0][0];
const End_Date = headers[0][1];
const Project_Name = headers[0][2];
const New_End_Date = headers[0][3];
const Contact_Finance = headers[0][5];
const Update_client = headers[0][6];
const Project_Leader = headers[0][7];
const Email = headers[0][11];

const lr = ws.getLastRow();
const tableRangeValues=ws.getRange(2,1, lr-1,9).getDisplayValues();

const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Notify") 
htmlTemplate.Project_Code = Project_Code;
htmlTemplate.End_Date= End_Date;
htmlTemplate.Project_Name= Project_Name;
htmlTemplate.New_End_Date=Complete;
htmlTemplate.Contact_Finance=Contact_Finance;
htmlTemplate.Update_client=Upadate_client;
htmlTemplate.Project_Leader=Project_Leader;
htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues=tableRangeValues;

const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();


// This is the part where email loop should happen? and only send emails to individual project leaders listing only the projects they work on.

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: // emails based on loops?
subject: 'Projects Ending',
htmlBody: htmlForEmail,
//Logger.log(tableRangeValues);
 });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't understand about `could not get it to work.` and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and be specific regarding where do you got stuck.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for responding. What I mean is I don't know how to do it and need help with the code

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to separate 1 array into multiple arrays by a key value

I suggest using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to organize your array of rows into an object that has emails as keys and arrays of rows as values (example below).
You'll end up with

```js
{
 "person1@email.com": [[value1],[value2],[value3]],
 "person2@email.com": [[value1],[value2],[value3]],
 // etc.
}
```

See below for a reducer that is specific to your needs, but in general the idea is

```js
function reducer(object, arrayOfValues) {
  const key = arrayOfValues[INDEX_OF_KEY];
  if (!(key in object)) object[key] = [];
  object[key].push(arrayOfValues);
  return object;
}

const groupedByKey = valuesFromSheet.reduce(reducer, {});
```

You can setup a loop through an Object with a relatively recent addition to the global `Object`: `Object.entries()`.  This will return an array of arrays so you can send your email with `Array.prototype.forEach` (example below).

For each email, create a new template.  You should take advantage of Apps Script's templating ability to modularize your templates. When you add all your styling in and then start adding scriplet tags `<? ?>` it can become a real mess.  I have demonstarted below how you can separate the table template from the main email template and end up with nested templates.  This is much more manageable and debuggable/testable.

Finally, I also always recommend defining your headings in one place (see the `HEADINGS` object below) so you can easily change up the heading order later without updating the code in multiple places (an easy way to introduce a bug into your script).

## Code.gs

```js
const HEADINGS = {
  PROJECT_CODE: 0,
  END_DATE: 1,
  PROJECT_NAME: 2,
  NEW_END_DATE: 3,
  CONTACT_FINANCE: 5,
  UPDATE_CLIENT: 6,
  PROJECT_LEADER: 7,
  LAST_NAME: 8,
  FULL_NAME: 9,
  EMAIL: 11
};

function Getdata(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Projects");
  const headers = makeHeaders(ws.getRange("A1:J").getValues()[0]);
  const lastRow = ws.getLastRow();
  const tableRangeValues = ws
    .getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, HEADINGS.EMAIL + 1)
    .getDisplayValues();
  const groupedByEmail = tableRangeValues.reduce(emailReducer, {});
  Object.entries(groupedByEmail).forEach(function(emailGroup) {
    const [email, values] = emailGroup;
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: "Projects Ending",
      htmlBody: makeHtmlEmail(values[0][HEADINGS.FULL_NAME], headers, values)
    });
  });
}

function emailReducer(groups, row) {
  const email = row[HEADINGS.EMAIL];
  if (!(email in groups)) groups[email] = [];
  groups[email].push(row.slice(HEADINGS.PROJECT_CODE, HEADINGS.FULL_NAME + 1));
  return groups;
}

function makeHtmlEmail(name, header, values) {
  const emailTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Notify");
  emailTemplate.name = name;
  emailTemplate.header = header;
  emailTemplate.values = values;
  return emailTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
}

function makeTable(header, values) {
  const table = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("table");
  table.header = header;
  table.values = values;
  return table.evaluate().getContent();
}

function makeHeaders(headerRow) {
  return [
    headerRow[HEADINGS.PROJECT_CODE],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.END_DATE],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.PROJECT_NAME],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.NEW_END_DATE],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.CONTACT_FINANCE],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.UPDATE_CLIENT],
    headerRow[HEADINGS.PROJECT_LEADER]
  ];
}
```

## Notify.html

```html
<body>
  <head><!-- style, etc... omitted for clarity --></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi <?= name ?></p>
    <!-- details omitted for clarity -->
    <h4> Project Details </h4>
    <?!= makeTable(header, values) ?>
  </body>
</body>
```

## table.html

```html
<!-- styling omitted for clarity -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <? header.forEach(heading => { ?>
      <th><?= heading ?></th>
    <? }) ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <? values.forEach(row => { ?>
    <tr>
    <? row.forEach(value => { ?>
      <td><?= value ?></td>
    <? }); ?>
    </tr>
  <? }); ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution in grouping per email. I have edited my code based on your suggestion but am only able to pass the headers to html table. Could you kindly explain to me how the reducer works, as I am unable to get the table values passed as well. Thanks

Comment: @willy - happy to help.  can you elaborate on "I am unable to get the table values passed as well"?  Do you get an error message?  Do you just get nothing in the email?  The reducer should just be producing an object with keys of emails and values that are arrays of arrays, like my example `{"email@a.com": [[],[],[]]}`; if you `console.log(groupedByEmail)` is there anything wrong with the data inside? If not, then no need to worry about the reducer.  Let me know where you lose the values.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I don't get any error message and my console displays emails and valuses just as you have elaborated on your example. The thing is I am able to get table headers to the email but I am having a challenge getting the table data as well passed to the eamil. I am lost on what I might not be doing correctly on the table data to pull the table data to HTML table. I apologize for the poor English, but I hope you are getting my concern.

Comment: @willy - try observing the table data at each step.  Before you use it in the template, console.log the table data.  Inside the template, you can add somewhere `DEBUG: <?= JSON.stringify(tableData) ?>` and/or `DEBUG: type of table data is <?= typeof tableData ?>` I call tableData "values" in my code, maybe its just a naming issue?  It is unfortunate the online editor does not include a static JavaScript linter to catch bugs like that.

Comment: I think this challenge arises from `Getdata()` function. When I `Logger.log(email)`  I get `johdoes@test.com` but when I do `Logger.log(values)`, I get `[[], [], [], []]`. I Thought when grouping by email, it will also have the row data in values grouped with the email. So in essence values are empty and are passed to the other functions as empty array and therefore nothing to append to the HTML table. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: @willy - those should not be empty, so it must be the `.slice` of the row that has wrong indexes.  Try not slicing at all in the reducer with `groups[email].push(row)` (no slice).  That will return the entire row.  Then fix the indexing.

Comment: Many thanks. This actually works. One last question, when sending emails, MailApp gets the range from `const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, HEADINGS.EMAIL + 1).getDisplayValues();` The challenge is that It includes the header row while looping through the emails, I have adjusted a few parameters, but still it captures that row in sending email thus throwing an **invalid email** error. What would be a quick fix for this?.  Could it be the `HEADINGS.EMAIL + 1` part of the code?. Also, I would like to avoid passing the email addresses to the HTML table Again thanks in advance.

Comment: @willy - Re: header row - just adjust the range in `tableRangeValues` to only include rows past the header row(s).  All my HEADINGS constants are zero indexed, so when using the `getRange` API, you have to `+1` to include that heading, i.e. `HEADINGS.EMAIL + 1` means "stop at the email column, inclusive".   Where I then trimmed off the email was in the reducer with the `.slice(start, stopExclusive)`.  `.slice`'s stop is exclusive, _but_ it is _zero-indexed_ so we still can use the `HEADINGS.FOO + 1` to say "stop at the foo column, inclusive".  In other words, put the slice back in!